# Limitar de uno a tres dígitos

Tags: python

Quiero limitar el número de dígitos a solo tres. Intenté usar este código pero obtengo solo errores.

```py
import numpy as np
def menu_principal():
  opciones={
     "1":("comprar entradas.1", accion1),
      "2":("ubicaciones.2",accion2),
      "3":("lista de asistentes.3",acccion3),
      "4":("mostrar ganancias.4",accion4),
      "5":("salir",salir)
}
  generar_menu(opciones,"5")


def accion1():
  print("ha elegido opcion 1")
  entrada=Int(input("ingrese el numero de entradas que desea comprar"))
```

> Soy estudiante de primer año y empecé con programación hace unos meses, y no he entendido varias cosas simples o por mala explicación o por otros motivos.

Comment: La función `Int` no existe. `int` sí. Podrías leer el número como texto, te quedas con los primeros 3 caracteres y conviertes eso al tipo entero.

Comment: No conviertas la cadena que ingreso el usuario a entero. Dejala como cadena y utiliza la funcion len para conocer la cantidad de caracteres. Si se trata de una cadena llena de numeros, eso devolvera la cantidad de digitos. El resto es hacer la correspondiente comparacion.

Comment: vale gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada Nicolas c: